# Dropdown Tied to ENUM now needs multilingual text

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, multilingual

Dropdown control is initialized like this:

```
lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PriceLevel));
```

And at lot of places its value is accessed like:

```
(PriceLevel)priceLookUpEdit.EditValue;
```

Now we are implementing multilingual functionality. Is there a way to change the text of dropdown values without breaking the link with the enum?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropdown in ASP.NET uses items which contain a text and a value. Winforms should have a similar approach.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx

Comment: What you are saying is correct but does not apply in the above case. Please try and check.